# Python: import only specific methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Let's consider the following example to illustrate my problem. I have two modules, for example:

`file_1.py`

```
def funct_1():
    'some code here'
```

`file_2.py`

```
from file_1 import funct_1
def funct_2():
    'some code here that is calling funct_1()'
```

Now, from another file I can do the following:

```
from file_2.py import funct_2, funct_1
```

My question is: is there a way to make the import of `funct_1` not possible in the third file?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No. If the module makes the name accessible via import, it can be used by anyone that can import the module. (Even taking a deep dive into the import mechanism as described in the documentation for the `importlib` module, I don't think there is a way for an import to know who is requesting the module.)

Comment: The only way would be to remove the ```from file_1 import funct_1``` from file_2.  This still won't make it impossible to import file_1 from any other file.